# PrimeNG Component Menu Steps, how can i use the ui-steps-incomplete

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular6, primeng

i use the component of PrimeNG: Steps

it works but how can i use the ui-steps-incomplete?

```css
:host >>> .ui-steps .ui-steps-item {
  width: 20%;
}

:host >>> .ui-steps.steps-custom .ui-steps-item .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #0081c2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

:host >>> .ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number {
  color: transparent;
}

:host >>> .ui-steps ui-steps-incomplete {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p-steps [model]="items" [(activeIndex)]="routingIndex" [readonly]="false" ></p-steps>
```

Comment: Please correct your tags.. Sure you are using PrimeFaces the JSF component suite?

Comment: Which version of PrimeNG did you use?

Comment: i use primeng: 6.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It's already automatically applied on the inactive state. 
If you look at the HTML generated, PrimeNG creates a list item with the class applied as followed:

```
<li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default ui-state-complete ui-state-disabled ui-steps-incomplete ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">...</li>
```

Comment: ok but how can i use that? in my code is all steps in backgroundcolor: white